# Fusion Tables API v2 still giving "Response size is larger than 10 MB. Please use media download." Error

Tags: google-fusion-tables

The text here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/migration_guide implies that the 10MB limit not in effect for API v2, or that an alternative service "Media download" could be used for large responses.

The API Reference here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/ does not have any information regarding the 10MB limit, or how you use "media download" to recieve your request.

How do I work around the 10MB limit for Fusion Tables API v2? I can't seem to find documentation that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

To use media-download simply add the parameter `alt=media` to the URL

Comment: It seems (although I cannot find it documented) that this is only supported for GET requests, unlike normal queries which work with POST requests.  Just in case this helps anyone else...

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Google's [API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/), the 'media download' is specified by using a specific method. For the [Python library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fusiontables/v2/python/latest/fusiontables_v2.query.html#sqlGet), there are two versions of the SQL query methods: `sql*()` and `sql*_media()` (and this is very likely true for the other client libraries as well).

Example usage:

```
# Build the googleapiclient service
FusionTables = build('fusiontables', 'v2', credentials=credentials);
query = 'select * from <table id>';

# "standard" query, returning fusiontables#sqlresponse JSON:
jsonRequest = FusionTables.query().sqlGet(sql = query);
jsonResponse = jsonRequest.execute();

# alt=media query, returning a CSV-formatted bytestring (in Python, at least):
bytestrRequest = FusionTables.query().sqlGet_media(sql = query);
byteResponse = bytestrRequest.execute();
```

As [Kerry mentions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602166/fusion-tables-api-v2-still-giving-response-size-is-larger-than-10-mb-please-us?rq=1#comment84098279_34668965), media format queries that are too large to be sent as a GET request will fail (while regular format queries of the same length succeed provided the query result is less than 10 MB). In the python client, this failure appears as a `HTTP 502: Bad Gateway` error.

Also note that `ROWID`s are currently not returned in the media response format.